# as3 hitTestObject() to hit all

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite, removechild

In my game I have person who shoots and I need if the bullet hit somthing to delete the sprite.

```
var i = 1;
var f:Function;
addChild(bullet);
bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, f = function(){ 
    bullet.x += movex*i;
    bullet.y += movey*i;
    i++;
});
```

How to make `hitTestObject()` with everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of techniques for collision detection, however, the method to  use depends on the target object's shape. Pixel perfect hittesting is the most accurate collision detection method, although this is very slow. Geometrical hittesting is probably the fastest and can be very accurate if done correctly. One disadvantage using `hitTestObject` is that it's quite slow. So my opinion in case you need to handle a large pool of object is to use alternative methods for collision detection.

Definitely for object to object collision detection you need to loop over each target object placed into an array (but for performance improvements into a `<Vector>`) and test if the bullet is hitting the destination object.

```
bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, testCollision);

private function testCollision(e: Event) {        
    bullet.x += moveX*i;
    bullet.y += moveY*i;

    for (var j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {     
        if (bullet.hitTestObject(objects[j])) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    i++;
};
```

It's worth to read these articles for further explanations:

http://plasticsturgeon.com/2011/03/actionscript-collision-detection-u-circle-circle-collision-detection/

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/25/strategies-for-optimizing-collision-detection-with-bitmapdata-hittest/

And here is a library which do the heavy work:
http://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/

Comment: how can i use this library (nothing in the wiki)

Comment: Here is a very short description how you can use it: http://www.stanford.edu/~aleeper/EPGY/samples/HowtoUsetheCollisionDetectionKit.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle it like this (I'm assuming the bullets are MovieClips you are adding from the library).

I'm using zombies and plants as examples of MovieClips already on the stage, which you are manually passing into the liveObjects array.

For larger scale games obviously you wouldn't hard code, but I'm trying to abtract away the extra stuff to make the example easier to understand)

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var liveObjects:Array = [
  zombie1, // A MovieClip on the stage
  zombie2, // ditto
  zombie3, // ditto
  plant1,  // ditto
  plant2   // ditto
];

// Create bullet
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
bullet.x = 200;
bullet.y = 200;
addChild( bullet );
bullet.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, f );

var i:int = 1;
var moveX:int = 1;
var moveY:int = 1;
function f( e:Event ){ 
  var thisBullet:MovieClip = ( e.currentTarget as MovieClip );
  thisBullet.x += moveX * i;
  thisBullet.y += moveY * i;
  i++;

  for( var j:int; j < liveObjects.length; j++ ) {
    if( thisBullet.hitTestObject( liveObjects[ j ] ) ) {
        trace( "Hit " + liveObjects[ j ] );
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: That would be useful if i really added them with MovieClip (i make it with sprite).Anyway, thanks for the help i think i will use it later on the game

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your intention, but your code seems to recommend adding a separate ENTER_FRAME listener for every bullet in the game, as opposed to a single game loop? May I ask why?

Comment: I far from recommend that - but I am extending the code given in the question. Perhaps, in his case he has only 1 bullet (I don't know because he hasn't outlined that) - so I need to go on the assumption he knows his project and has chosen to add the event listener to the bullet, upon which I extended the code to answer the question around hit tests (and not event listeners). But I whole heatedly agree with game loops

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have some array that holds a reference to all of the enemy sprites. Just loop through that calling hitTestObject() on it with the bullet.