# Colliding two objects in a canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

Ok so I'm making a two-player Pac-Man game for my JavaScript class and I'm having trouble with having Pac-Man collide with the walls. The four walls that line the outside of the canvas work just fine so he stays in it but he goes right through all of the wall objects inside the canvas that make up the maze.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var blockSize = 12;
var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;
var score = 0;
var drawBorder = function () {
  ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
  drawWalls();
};
var Wall = function(x, y, width, height)
{
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}
var drawWalls = function()
{
  ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
  //scoreboards
  var wall1 = new Wall(0, 60, 650, 12);
  var wall2 = new Wall(220, 0, 12, 60);
  var wall3 = new Wall(430, 0, 12, 60);
  //verticle walls
  var wall = new Wall(36, 96, 12, 216);
  var wall4 = new Wall(36, 372, 12, 240);
  var wall5 = new Wall(600, 372, 12, 240);
  var wall6 = new Wall(600, 96, 12, 216);
  var wall7 = new Wall(300, 132, 12, 180);
  var wall8 = new Wall(336, 132, 12, 180);
  var wall9 = new Wall(300, 372, 12, 204);
  var wall10 = new Wall(336, 372, 12, 204);
  var wall11 = new Wall(168, 372, 12, 204);
  var wall12 = new Wall(468, 372, 12, 204);
  var wall13 = new Wall(468, 132, 12, 180);
  var wall14 = new Wall(168, 132, 12, 180);
  //horizontal walls
  var wall15 = new Wall(72, 96, 240, 12);
  var wall16 = new Wall(72, 336, 240, 12);
  var wall17 = new Wall(336, 96, 240, 12);
  var wall18 = new Wall(336, 336, 240, 12);
  var wall19 = new Wall(72, 600, 240, 12);
  var wall20 = new Wall(336, 600, 240, 12);
  var wall21 = new Wall(72, 216, 204, 12);
  var wall22 = new Wall(72, 468, 204, 12);
  var wall23 = new Wall(372, 216, 204, 12);
  var wall24 = new Wall(372, 468, 204, 12);
  //square walls 1
  var wall25 = new Wall(72, 132, 84, 72);
  var wall26 = new Wall(192, 132, 84, 72);
  var wall27 = new Wall(72, 240, 84, 72);
  var wall28 = new Wall(192, 240, 84, 72);
  //square walls 2
  var wall29 = new Wall(372, 132, 84, 72);
  var wall30 = new Wall(492, 132, 84, 72);
  var wall31 = new Wall(372, 240, 84, 72);
  var wall32 = new Wall(492, 240, 84, 72);
  //square walls 3
  var wall33 = new Wall(72, 372, 84, 84);
  var wall34 = new Wall(192, 372, 84, 84);
  var wall35 = new Wall(72, 492, 84, 84);
  var wall36 = new Wall(192, 492, 84, 84);
  //square walls 4
  var wall37 = new Wall(372, 372, 84, 84);
  var wall38 = new Wall(492, 372, 84, 84);
  var wall39 = new Wall(372, 492, 84, 84);
  var wall40 = new Wall(492, 492, 84, 84);
};
Pac.prototype.checkCollision = function (head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBlocks - 1);
  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

  return wallCollision;
};
```

Sorry if I didn't do the proper format. I'm new on here and this is my first post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [as3 hitTestObject() to hit all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089241/as3-hittestobject-to-hit-all)

Answer (score 0):

Just as general advice, with any type of collision system, you never want to bind your physics code to your drawing code. So you should not be measuring / dividing by the number of pixels per block. You should be defining the number of blocks as a whole number and comparing the pac man's whole or fractional position in blocks to that. One not-so-obvious reason for this is that Javascript does not always perform floating point calculations perfectly. That may be a problem you're running into. In any case, if your width in blocks is not a whole number, or the head isn't positioned at a whole number, this code won't work. You really want to be checking whether the head is WITHIN a block, and if so, take it back to its previous position. Not just if it is exactly at the edge of a block.

The better way to write this code is to define the walls in their block position, define the pacman in its block position, and then during the draw call you would multiply those up by whatever number of pixels you want it to display at. Then check whether any of the pacman's boundaries are within any of the wall blocks. The typical way to structure this each frame is to take the user input first, check the physics as they would be if you continued with the motion, then move the physics, then draw the scene.